# How to group the below array data to the mentioned structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, ecmascript-6

Currently I have an array data structure as mentioned below under "Actual". Want to group it in a way to get the desired structure as mentioned below in the "expected".

I tried using lodash groupBy , mapToValues and map to arrange it in the structure I want but couldn't make it possible.

Actual:

```
const candyDataSoldByEachDayInYear2000 = [
  {
    candyName: 'snickers',
    data: [{
      date: "2000-01-01", sold: 100
    }, {
      date: "2000-01-02", sold: 110
    }]
  }, {
    candyName: 'kitkat',
    data: [{
      date: "2000-01-01", sold: 80
    }, {
      date: "2000-01-02", sold: 70
    }]
  }, {
    candyName: 'twix',
    data: [{
      date: "2000-01-01", sold: 60
    }, {
      date: "2000-01-02", sold: 50
    }]
  }, {
    candyName: 'milkyway',
    data: [{
      date: "2000-01-01", sold: 60
    }, {
      date: "2000-01-02", sold: 70
    }]
  }, {
    candyName: 'skittles',
    data: [{
      date: "2000-01-01", sold: 120
    }, {
      date: "2000-01-02", sold: 110
    }]
  }];
```

Expected:

```
const candyDataSoldByEachDayInYear2000 = [
  {
    date: "2000-01-01",
    candySold: {
      snickers: 100,
      kitkat: 80,
      twix: 60,
      milkyway: 60,
      skittles: 120
    }
  },
  {
    date: "2000-01-02",
    candySold: {
      snickers: 110,
      kitkat: 70,
      twix: 50,
      milkyway: 70,
      skittles: 110
    }
  }
];
```

.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()` with `Array.forEach()` create an object with dates keys, add the candies to the relevant date, and convert to array with `Array.values()`:

```js
const candyDataSoldByEachDayInYear2000 = [{"candyName":"snickers","data":[{"date":"2000-01-01","sold":100},{"date":"2000-01-02","sold":110}]},{"candyName":"kitkat","data":[{"date":"2000-01-01","sold":80},{"date":"2000-01-02","sold":70}]},{"candyName":"twix","data":[{"date":"2000-01-01","sold":60},{"date":"2000-01-02","sold":50}]},{"candyName":"milkyway","data":[{"date":"2000-01-01","sold":60},{"date":"2000-01-02","sold":70}]},{"candyName":"skittles","data":[{"date":"2000-01-01","sold":120},{"date":"2000-01-02","sold":110}]}];
  
const result = Object.values(candyDataSoldByEachDayInYear2000.reduce((r, { candyName, data }) => {
  data.forEach(({ date, sold }) => {
    if(!r[date]) r[date] = { date, candySold: {} };
    
    const cs = r[date].candySold;
    
    cs[candyName] = (cs[candyName] || 0) + sold;
  });

  return r;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach not using a library:

```js
const collectSales = (candy) => Object .entries (candy .reduce (
  (a, {candyName, data}) => data .reduce (
    (a, {date, sold, o = a[date] || {}, c = o[candyName] || 0}) => 
      ({...a, [date]: {...o, [candyName]: c + sold}}),
    a
  ),
  {}
))
.map ( ([date, candySold]) => ({date, candySold}) )

const candyDataSoldByEachDayInYear2000 = [{candyName:"snickers",data:[{date:"2000-01-01",sold:100},{date:"2000-01-02",sold:110}]},{candyName:"kitkat",data:[{date:"2000-01-01",sold:80},{date:"2000-01-02",sold:70}]},{candyName:"twix",data:[{date:"2000-01-01",sold:60},{date:"2000-01-02",sold:50}]},{candyName:"milkyway",data:[{date:"2000-01-01",sold:60},{date:"2000-01-02",sold:70}]},{candyName:"skittles",data:[{date:"2000-01-01",sold:120},{date:"2000-01-02",sold:110}]}];

console .log (
  collectSales (candyDataSoldByEachDayInYear2000)
)
```

This version uses `reduce` to turn the data into something like:

```
{
    "2000-01-01": {
        kitkat: 80,
        milkyway: 60,
        skittles: 120,
        snickers: 100,
        twix: 60
    },
    "2000-01-02": {
        kitkat: 70,
        milkyway: 70,
        skittles: 110,
        snickers: 110,
        twix: 50
    }
}
```

and then wraps that result with `Object.entries` followed by a simple `map` statement.

### Update

The above is altered from this version:

```js
const collectSales = (candy) => Object.entries ( candy .reduce (
  (a, {candyName, data}) => data .reduce (
    (a, {date, sold}) => 
      ({...a, [date]: {...(a[date] || {}), [candyName]: ((a[date] || {})[candyName] || 0) + sold}}),
    a
  ),
  {}
))
.map ( ([date, candySold]) => ({date, candySold}) )

const candyDataSoldByEachDayInYear2000 = [{candyName:"snickers",data:[{date:"2000-01-01",sold:100},{date:"2000-01-02",sold:110}]},{candyName:"kitkat",data:[{date:"2000-01-01",sold:80},{date:"2000-01-02",sold:70}]},{candyName:"twix",data:[{date:"2000-01-01",sold:60},{date:"2000-01-02",sold:50}]},{candyName:"milkyway",data:[{date:"2000-01-01",sold:60},{date:"2000-01-02",sold:70}]},{candyName:"skittles",data:[{date:"2000-01-01",sold:120},{date:"2000-01-02",sold:110}]}];

console .log (
  collectSales (candyDataSoldByEachDayInYear2000)
)
```

It is a definite clean-up that avoids some ugly repetition.